# Add lambda to predicate - VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, lambda, predicate

I have the above code :

```
if (i=0)
 pred = (Function(d) d.n_pratica = n_pratica)
else
 pred = (Function(d) d.n_polizza = n_polizza)
```

i need to add to pred another lambda expression to the one that just exists :

`(Function(d) d.n_anagrafico = n_anagrafico)` //this function is in another if statement so i can't add it directly to the stametent wrote before.

So `if i=0`
the result need to be

```
 pred = (Function(d) d.n_pratica = n_pratica andalso d.n_anagrafico = n_anagrafico) 

else

 pred = (Function(d) d.n_polizza= n_polizza andalso d.n_anagrafico = n_anagrafico)
```

"Pred" is a `Func (of object , boolean)`.

Thanks

Comment: `pred` is definitely not `Func(Of Object , Boolean)`. Can you please post a proper object model?

Comment: Why should not ? i declared it as Func(Of Object , Boolean) and the statement (Function(d) d.n_pratica = n_pratica) returns me this type .

Comment: The `n_pratica` is not a property/field of `Object` so it can't possibly be `Func(Of Object, Boolean)`. Have you got `Option Strict On`?

Answer (score 0):

This code should help:

```
Sub Main

    Dim n_pratica As String = "Foo"
    Dim n_anagrafico As String = "Bar"

    Dim pred As Func(Of SomeClass, Boolean) = Function (d) d.n_pratica = n_pratica

    Dim pred_original = pred

    pred = Function (d) pred_original(d) AndAlso d.n_anagrafico = n_anagrafico

    Dim sc = New SomeClass()
    sc.n_pratica = n_pratica
    sc.n_anagrafico = n_anagrafico

    Console.WriteLine(pred(sc))

    sc.n_pratica = "Qaz"

    Console.WriteLine(pred(sc))

End Sub

Public Class SomeClass
    Public n_pratica As String
    Public n_anagrafico As String
End Class
```

It outputs `True` then `False`.

As a word of advice - please ensure that you always have `Option Strict On` for all of your VB coding.